# Why is this multi-threaded bubble sort taking so long?

Tags: multithreading, scala, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement a more efficient bubble sort for a homework problem which requires us to create a list of 3,000,000 random doubles and use multi-threading to divide the list into quarters and simultaneously bubble sort each quarter. This is supposed to take ~7 minutes for each quarter (750,000 numbers), but on my computer, even sorting 10,000 doubles (2,500 per quarter) takes about 6 minutes and sorting a list of 1,000,000 integers isn't finished after over an hour. I am using a 2012 Macbook Pro. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this program is taking so long?

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object bubbleSortTest extends App{
  val size:Int = 10000
  val numDivs:Int = 4
  val list = ListBuffer.fill(size)(Random.nextDouble*100) 
//create list of 10000 random doubles

  val divs = ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Double]]()
  for(i <- 0 until numDivs) 
    divs += list.grouped(list.length/numDivs).toList(i).to[ListBuffer]
//divide list into quarters and put quarters into new list divs

  val s0 = new Sorter("s0",list) 
//create sorter for entire list
  val sorters = divs.zipWithIndex.map(x => new Sorter(s"s${x._2 + 1}", x._1)) //create sorter for each quarter

  s0.start()
  for(s <- sorters)
    s.start()

}

class Sorter(name:String, list:ListBuffer[Double]) extends Thread {

  override def run() {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    sort(list)
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println(s"$name done: ${(t1-t0)/1e9}s")
    //println(list)
  }

  def sort(list:ListBuffer[Double]): List[Double] = {
    var didSwap = false
    for(i <- 0 until list.length-1) {
      //println(s"$getName: $i")
      if(list(i)>list(i+1)) {
        didSwap = true
        var temp = list(i)
        list(i) = list(i+1)
        list(i+1) = temp
      }
    }

    if(didSwap)
      return sort(list)
    else
      return list.toList
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using ListBuffer. A linked list has a potential problem that every individual step during a traversal of a linked list can entail a cache miss. Try the other mutable data structures such as Array or ArrayBuffer. Because contiguous slots in Array or ArrayBuffer exist side-by-side in memory, you will have fewer cache misses, which means your sort should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ListBuffer` is a list not an array, with each element of the list pointing to the next one rather than being in a single block of memory. This means that taking the `length` of a `ListBuffer` means counting every element in the list. And getting element `i` from the the `ListBuffer` means stepping through `i` elements of the list.

Indexing a `ListBuffer` is `O(n)` and in the worst case Bubble Sort is `O(n^2)`, so your algorithm is `O(n^3)` which get very slow with large `n`.